# Return complex types from PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I'm trying to return a matrix of values from a Grouped Map Pandas UDF.

When defining the schema, I'm giving Array(Array(DoubleType())), but that causes to return only the first row of the matrix with all other values as None.

Here's what I tried:

```
myschema = StructType([
  StructField('my_id',  StringType()),
  StructField('matrix', ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType())) )
]);
cols = list(map(lambda s: s.__dict__['name'], myschema))

@F.pandas_udf(myschema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_function(data):
  myID = 'Hello'

  matrix = [
    [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
    [4.4, 5.5, 6.6],
    [7.7, 8.8, 9.9]
  ]

  return pd.DataFrame([[ myID, matrix ]], columns=cols)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(['id1', 'id2'], columns=['ID']))
df.groupBy('ID').apply(my_function).collect()
```

And as a result, I have:

> Row(my_id=u'Hello', matrix=[[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], None, None])

Of course, returning a not nested array works without any problem.

```
myschema = StructType([
  StructField('my_id',  StringType()),
  StructField('matrix', ArrayType(DoubleType()))
]);
cols = list(map(lambda s: s.__dict__['name'], myschema))

@F.pandas_udf(myschema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_function(data):
  myID = 'Hello'

  matrix = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]

  return pd.DataFrame([[ myID, matrix ]], columns=cols)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(['id1', 'id2'], columns=['ID']))
df.groupBy('ID').apply(my_function).collect()
```

And the result:

> Row(my_id=u'Hello', matrix=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3])

Is there something wrong with the schema?

Comment: Works fine in Spark 2.4.0 / pyarrow 0.11.0.

Comment: I just checked my Spark version.
Here's what I found:
Databricks Runtime Version
5.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11)

Comment: In that case it might be more a question to Databricks support - if it works with open distribution it must be something they've messed up internally and it's unlikely you'll get help here.